# assertj Assertions assertThat is not resolved

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, assertj

Weird behavior. I've got a vanilla spring boot project I made with initializr. The `build.gradle` is below and as you can see it loaded up the test dependency for spring boot starter test, which includes the assertj package.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.acme'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

However, I have my first test component here

```java
package com.foretold.astrocalc.app.controllers;

import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class ChartControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private ChartController controller;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception{
        assertThat(controller).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

And IJ is telling me that it cannot resolve the symbol assertThat. It loads up to `Assertions` in the import statement and that's in. When I click into the `Assertions` class I see the public method `assertThat`. Is there some IJ setting that's screwing up the static import?

It does work to just import `Assertions` and use the method with dot notation, but why won't the static import work?

Comment: better add an explicit assertj testImplementation dependency IMO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we want to write assertions in AssertJ, we have to use static assertThat method instead.
This means that you have to import it like following instead:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
```